# How to add Fenom Template in Yii2?

Tags: templates, yii2, components

I'm trying to add [Fenom Tempate](https://github.com/fenom-template/fenom) to *Yii2* application, but I'm getting a lot of different kinds errors.

I've tried to create a component `ViewRenderer` and to write code like [here](https://github.com/y2i/yii2-fenom/blob/master/ViewRenderer.php), but with my own namespace:

```js
namespace app\components\fenom;

use Yii;

use yii\base\View;
use yii\base\ViewRenderer as BaseViewRenderer;

class ViewRenderer extends BaseViewRenderer {
    /**
     * @var string the directory, where stores templates.
     */
    public $templatePath = '@app/views';
    /**
     * @var string the directory, where stores compiled templates in PHP files.
     */
    public $compilePath = '@runtime/Fenom/compile';
    /**
     * @var int|array bit-mask or array of Fenom settings.
     * @see https://github.com/bzick/fenom/blob/master/docs/en/configuration.md#template-settings
     */
    public $options = 0;
    /**
     * @var \Fenom object that renders templates.
     */
    public $fenom;
    public function init() {
        $this->fenom =  \yii\fenom\Fenom::factory($this->templatePath, $this->compilePath, $this->options);
    }
    
    public function render($view, $file, $params) {
        $params['this'] = $view;

        return $this->fenom->fetch($file, $params);
    }
}
```

Added this component to `config`

```
'components' => [
        'view' => [
            'class' => 'yii\web\View',
            'renderers' => [
                'tpl' => [
                    'class' => 'app\components\fenom\ViewRenderer',
                    'options' => [
                        'auto_reload' => true,
                    ],
                ],
                // ...
            ],
        ],
```

But I'm getting errors. Bad namespace or unwritable directory or another and another errors.

So, my **question is**: How to add *Fenom* to *Yii2*? What and Where should I write (in config, components, or other folders)? What way is the fastest and the most efficient?

Please tell me how to do it properly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I did it. I'm not sure if this is correct, but...

I made the **fenom** folder inside the **components** folder. I put files from the **src** folder of [fenom repo](https://github.com/fenom-template/fenom/tree/master/src) into the `/components/fenom`.
Also in this folder I created a `ViewRenderer.php` file. It contains code:

```
<?php

namespace app\components\fenom;

use Yii;
use yii\base\ViewRenderer as BaseViewRenderer;

class ViewRenderer extends BaseViewRenderer {
    /**
     * @var string the directory, where stores templates.
     */
    public $templatePath = '@app/views';
    /**
     * @var string the directory, where stores compiled templates in PHP files.
     */
    public $compilePath = '@runtime/Fenom/compile';
    /**
     * @var int|array bit-mask or array of Fenom settings.
     * @see https://github.com/bzick/fenom/blob/master/docs/en/configuration.md#template-settings
     */
    public $options = ['auto_reload' => true];
    /**
     * @var \Fenom object that renders templates.
     */
    public $fenom;


    public function init() {
        // put main Fenom class into the yii classmap
        Yii::$classMap['Fenom'] = __DIR__.'/Fenom.php';
        // call Fenom class autoloader (https://github.com/fenom-template/fenom/blob/master/docs/en/start.md#custom-loader)
        \Fenom::registerAutoload(__DIR__."./");
        // Yii::getAlias - because it's not understand Yii aliases???
        $this->fenom = \Fenom::factory(Yii::getAlias($this->templatePath), Yii::getAlias($this->compilePath), $this->options);
    }

    public function render($view, $file, $params) {
        $params['this'] = $view;

        $dirPath = '';
        // this is because Fenom do not understand absolute paths???
        if (strpos($file, 'views') != false)
            $dirPath = explode('views', $file)[1];
        if (strpos($file, 'widgets') != false)
            $dirPath = explode('widgets', $file)[1];
        if (strpos($file, 'modules') != false)
            $dirPath = explode('modules', $file)[1];

        return $this->fenom->fetch($dirPath, $params);
    }
}
```

I've added `ViewRenderer` component into the **config** file:

```
'components' => [
        'view' => [
            'class' => 'yii\web\View',
            'renderers' => [
                'tpl' => [
                    'class' => 'app\components\fenom\ViewRenderer',
                ],
            ],
        ],
        // ...
```

and created folders inside the **runtime** folder

```
- runtime
   - Fenom
       - compile
       - cache
```

`compile` - for compiled filed, `cache` - for cached filed

That's it.

---

For testing:

**/views/site/index.tpl** file contains:

```
{$testtext}
```

**/controllers/SiteController** → **actionIndex** contains:

```
public function actionIndex() {
    return $this->render('index.tpl', ['testtext' => 'It works! Test text']);        
}
```

result:

[image]

Something like that...

Comment: You should try installing fenom with composer. You wouldn't need the first two lines in your init if you did. +1 for sticking with it. You should mark this as the answer.

Comment: @topher `You should try installing fenom with composer` - Yes...Don't know why, but I forgot that I can do that))

Answer (score 0):

## Installation

Since fenom is an extension on its own, you should use composer to install it. From the [docs](https://github.com/y2i/yii2-fenom#installation):

> The preferred way to install this extension is through [composer](http://getcomposer.org/download/).
>
> Either run
>
> ```
> php composer.phar require --prefer-dist y2i/yii2-fenom "*"
> ```
>
> or add
>
> ```
> "y2i/yii2-fenom": "*"
> ```
>
> to the require section of your `composer.json` file.

## Usage

The `class` element in your config file should be a fully qualified class name, not a path to the class file. As such, if installed using composer, you can use the following:

```
'class' => 'y2i\fenom\ViewRenderer'
```

Comment: of course I've changed a namespace of my component. I've copied only body of class from git repo..........(I put my component into the `componets/fenom` folder and  it have a `namespace app\components\fenom;` namespace)............... About installing from composer: I've tried, but it gives me an error: `The requested package y2i/yii2-fenom could not be found in any version, there may be a typo in the package name` ... that is why I started copying that class..... I think *yii2-fenom* is abandoned....

Comment: Yeah. This looks abandoned. There is also no y2i/yii2-fenom on packagist.org. Looks like you'll have to do it the hard way.

Comment: @topher Looks like you got y2i/yii2-fenom from the ViewRenderer sample; the composer install for Fenom is fenom/fenom.  See https://github.com/fenom-template/fenom

Comment: @sonofagun Even with that you'd have to implement your own ViewRenderer. That's what y2i/yii2-fenom was supposed to be.